# data can be seen in console but in db it is not inserting using mean stack

Tags: mongodb, mean

my model(cart.js)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema =  mongoose.Schema

var cartSchema = new Schema({
 prodId: { type: Number },
 img: { type: String },
 qnt: { type: Number },
 amt: { type: Number },
 name: { type: String },
 address: {type: String}
 })
 module.exports = mongoose.model('cart', cartSchema,'carts');
```

=====>
my routes(cart.js):

```
 router.post('/', (req, res) => {
 let cartData = req.body
 let cart = new Cart(cartData)
 console.log(req.body)
 cart.save((error, cart) => {
  if(error){
    console.log("Error: "+ error)
  }
  else{
    res.status(200).send(cart)
  }
})
```

})

there is no error in console .everything is fine but getting only _id,_v in database.
what is wrong ?please help me.

thanks in advance

Comment: What is logged for the req.body?

Comment: the cart items comes into req.body like this  {
    prodId: 2,
    img: 'assets/images/p2.jpg',
    nam: 'Cashew',
    qnt: '1',
    amt: '600'
  },
  {
    prodId: 3,
    img: 'assets/images/p3.jpg',
    nam: 'Pista',
    qnt: '1',
    amt: '800'
  } this i can see in terminal but in db not showing

Comment: If the req.body contains multiples like that, I don't think `new Cart(...)` will handle them

Comment: then how?what might be solution?